# Image alignment issue using gridlayout

Tags: android, layout, grid

I had some problem with the alignment for the picture when I export the APK to phone for test. The alignment is totally different and out of the grid.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="sg.edu.rp.c346.tictactoee.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/board"
        android:columnCount="4"
        android:rowCount="3"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/gridLayout">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView0"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:onClick="gameLogic"
            android:tag="0"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:onClick="gameLogic"
            android:tag="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:onClick="gameLogic"
            android:tag="2" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:onClick="gameLogic"
            android:tag="3"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
            android:onClick="gameLogic"
            android:tag="4"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:onClick="gameLogic"
            android:tag="5"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:onClick="gameLogic"
            android:tag="6"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView7"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
            android:onClick="gameLogic"
            android:tag="7"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView8"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:onClick="gameLogic"
            android:tag="8"/>

    </GridLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="#1eccd5"
        android:padding="35dp"
        android:id="@+id/winnerLayout">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Play Again"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:onClick="playAgain" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

It shows like this using android studio:

[image]

However, when I export it to my android phone, the alignment totally changes and out of grid, anyone able to help me ?

Comment: please share your adapter class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are new to `Android`. 
Android uses device's dimensions while creating any `view(screen)` on your device. 
Android supports different dimensions like,

1. hdpi
2. xhdpi
3. xxhdpi
4. xxxhdpi etc.

So for your case, Android System try to fit all views in absolute size given by you.

I suggest use `wrap_content` for `width` and `height` of your view.

You can modify your layout file as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:columnCount="4"
        android:rowCount="3">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:onClick="gameLogic"
            android:padding="30dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
            android:tag="0"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:onClick="gameLogic"
            android:padding="30dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
            android:tag="1"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:onClick="gameLogic"
            android:padding="30dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
            android:tag="2"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:onClick="gameLogic"
            android:padding="30dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
            android:tag="3"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:onClick="gameLogic"
            android:padding="30dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
            android:tag="4"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:onClick="gameLogic"
            android:padding="30dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
            android:tag="5"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:onClick="gameLogic"
            android:padding="30dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
            android:tag="6"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:onClick="gameLogic"
            android:padding="30dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
            android:tag="7"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:onClick="gameLogic"
            android:padding="30dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
            android:tag="8"/>

    </GridLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/winnerLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="#1eccd5"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="35dp"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="playAgain"
            android:text="Play Again"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

You can change `padding` and `src` as per your requirement.

Please add image how you want it if this differs!

For more information, Please check this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html).

Answer (score 0):

Add padding in your Image view

```
android:padding="10dp"
```

For example:

```
  <ImageView
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView0"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:onClick="gameLogic"
            android:tag="0"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />
```

This will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

- Change GridLayout to android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
- Add

  ```
  app:columnCount="3"
  app:rowCount="3"
  ```

  to GridView
- On ImageView use

  ```
  app:layout_columnWeight="1"
  app:layout_rowWeight="1"
  ```

instead of

```
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
```

xml file will look like this,

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="500dp"
    app:columnCount="3"
    app:orientation="horizontal"
    app:rowCount="3"
    app:useDefaultMargins="true">

        <ImageView
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:id="@+id/imageView0"
            android:tag="0"
            android:background="#ff0000" />

        <ImageView
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:onClick="gameLogic"
            android:tag="1"
            android:background="#ff0000"/>

        <ImageView
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:background="#ff0000"
            android:onClick="gameLogic"
            android:tag="2" />

        <ImageView
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:background="#ff0000"
            android:onClick="gameLogic"
            android:tag="3"/>

        <ImageView
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:background="#ff0000"
            android:onClick="gameLogic"
            android:tag="4"/>

        <ImageView
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:background="#ff0000"
            android:onClick="gameLogic"
            android:tag="5"/>

        <ImageView
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:id="@+id/imageView6"
            android:background="#ff0000"
            android:onClick="gameLogic"
            android:tag="6"/>

        <ImageView
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:id="@+id/imageView7"
            android:background="#ff0000"
            android:onClick="gameLogic"
            android:tag="7"/>

        <ImageView
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:id="@+id/imageView8"
            android:background="#ff0000"
            android:onClick="gameLogic"
            android:tag="8"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

[image]